# HTML/CSS the same div lengths

Tags: html, css, width

I have 3 divs (example below):

[image]

```
<ul>
<div class="parent">
<li>
  <div>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy
  </div>
</li>
</div>
<li>
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting 
  </div>
</li>
</div>
</div>
</ul>
```

And I want to all of them to have the same widths as the longest. The width of the longest should be the same as the text inside it plus some pixel (f.e. + 15px). The text will be changing so width should dynamically changing. Display has to be inline-table. 
Is it possible to do something like that in the HTML/CSS?

Comment: Share your basic HTML structure and we'll see.

Comment: I have added comment ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible using HTML/CSS. Here is the code snippet.

```css
.parent {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
}
.parent div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy
  </div>
  <div>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting 
  </div>
  <div>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the print 
  </div>
</div>
```

As per below code...

```css
ul {
    display: inline-block;
}
ul li {
    list-style: none;
}
li div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Thank You, I have added in the first post example of my code and the problem.

Comment: I have added the css code above as per your HTML. Try this.

Comment: You have something wrong in your HTML. In first, you have li inside div and in second, you have div inside li.